# How to refactor this node.js code, to avoid duplication

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-bot-service

I am trying to trying to setup a base skeleton for my demo project and writing my first node.js program. The below code is working for my first test, but it has duplicate - Getting connection, Executing a query (but a different one), parsing the sql output. I want to minimize this, because, I have to write more if-else blocks like that and it will become humongous and dirty code.

Database connection details are handled in **DatabaseManager.js**

**app.js**

Line #8 and #40:

```js
var connect = require('./DatabaseManager');
bot.dialog('profileDialog', (session) => {
    session.send('You reached the profile intent. You said \'%s\'.', session.message.text);
    console.log('Creating a connection');

    var userMessage = session.message.text;

    // Here is the FIrst block
    if (userMessage.indexOf('Email') >= 0) {
      session.send('Your are looking for your email');

      connect(function(connection) {
        console.log('Reading rows from the Table...');

        request = new Request("select Email from StudentProfile where ID=1", function(err, rowCount) {

          if (err) {
            console.log('ERROR in QUERY');
          } else {
            console.log(rowCount + ' rows');
          }
          connection.close();
        });

        request.on('row', function(columns) { // Iterate through the rows using a callback
          columns.forEach(function(column) {
            if (column.value === null) {
              console.log('NULL');
            } else {
              session.send(column.value);
            }
          });
        });
        connection.execSql(request);
      });
      session.endDialog();
      return;
    } //end of email id if

    //Here is the second block with repeated functionality, but a different query.
    connect(function(connection) {
      console.log('Reading rows from the Table...');

      request = new Request("select FNAME from StudentProfile where ID=1", function(err, rowCount) {

        if (err) {
          console.log('ERROR in QUERY');
        } else {
          console.log(rowCount + ' rows');
        }
        connection.close();
      });

      request.on('row', function(columns) { // Iterate through the rows using a callback
        columns.forEach(function(column) {
          if (column.value === null) {
            console.log('NULL');
          } else {
            session.send(column.value);
          }
        });
      });
      connection.execSql(request);
    });


  } //end of dialog

).triggerAction({
  matches: 'profile'
}) //end of trigger
```

I want to refactor this code to make it simple and reusable by other functionalities by passing required arguments.

I tired the below way, but `return (column.value);` statement is not working:

```
function queryDatabase(colname) {
    connect(function (connection) {
        request = new Request('select Email from StudentProfile where SUID=1', function (err, rowCount) {

            if (err) {
                console.log('ERROR in QUERY');
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(rowCount + ' rows');
            }
            connection.close();
        });

        request.on('row', function (columns) {  // Iterate through the rows using a callback
            columns.forEach(function (column) {
                if (column.value === null) {
                    console.log('NULL');
                } else {
                    console.log(column.value);
                    return (column.value);
                }
            });
        });
        connection.execSql(request);
    });
}
bot.dialog('profileDialog',(session) => {
    session.send('You reached the profile intent. You said \'%s\'.', session.message.text);
    console.log('Creating a connection');

    var userMessage = session.message.text;

    if( userMessage.indexOf('Email') >= 0){
        session.send('Your are looking for your email');
        var messg = queryDatabase('Email');
        console.log(messg);
       session.endDialog();
       return;
     } //end of email id if

     else {
       session.send('Looking for something else');
       session.endDialog();
       return;
     }


} //end of dialog

).triggerAction({
matches: 'profile'
}) //end of trigger
```

Comment: As usual when abstracting, put the duplicated code in a function and make everything that differs between the usages a parameter. Please show us your attempt.

Comment: @Bergi, I have added my attempt to the code. Almost there, but the `return (column.value);` is not returning the value to the caller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tired the below way, but `return (column.value);` statement is not working

Yes, you cannot use `return` here. Both because it is asynchronous, and because it might run multiple times in the `forEach` loop.

Instead, use a callback:

```
var connect = require('./DatabaseManager');

function queryDatabase(query, callback) {
//                            ^^^^^^^^
  connect(function(connection) {
    console.log('Reading rows from the Table...');

    const request = new Request(query, function(err, rowCount) {
//  ^^^^^ use local variable
      if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR in QUERY');
      } else {
        console.log(rowCount + ' rows');
      }
      connection.close();
    });

    request.on('row', function(columns) {
      columns.forEach(function(column) {
        if (column.value === null) {
          console.log('NULL');
        } else {
          callback(column.value);
//        ^^^^^^^^
        }
      });
    });
    connection.execSql(request);
  });
}
```

```
bot.dialog('profileDialog', (session) => {
  session.send('You reached the profile intent. You said \'%s\'.', session.message.text);
  console.log('Creating a connection');

  var userMessage = session.message.text;
  if (userMessage.indexOf('Email') >= 0) {
    session.send('Your are looking for your email');
    queryDatabase("select Email from StudentProfile where ID=1", function(value) {
//                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      session.send(value);
    });
    session.endDialog();
  } else {
    queryDatabase("select FNAME from StudentProfile where ID=1", function(value) {
//                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      session.send(value);
    });
  }
}).triggerAction({
  matches: 'profile'
})
```

Comment: yes this worked for me and also now able to understand what is this call back. As I mentioned, this is my first node js program. 

Can I say a callback is some kind of helper that carries the values in the event of Async ? or any plain English definition for this?

Any suggestions, if I want to move this whole `querydatabase()` function to other file, instead of keeping it here.

Comment: @NaniK [Callback functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_science)) are a very generic tool, they are not necessarily asynchronous. The function that you pass to `forEach` is a callback as well.

Comment: @NaniK Regarding using multiple code files, see https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html (or probably some more beginner-friendly nodejs modules tutorial, but I don't know any)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which connects, runs a query and then disconnects. It should look something like:

```
function execute(query, rowProcessor) {
    connect(function(connection) {
      console.log('Reading rows from the Table...');
      request = new Request(query, function(err, rowCount) {

        if (err) {
          console.log('ERROR in QUERY');
        } else {
          console.log(rowCount + ' rows');
        }
        connection.close();
        request.on('row', rowProcessor);
      });
}

function rowProcessor(columns) {
    columns.forEach(function(column) {
        if (column.value === null) {
            console.log('NULL');
        } else {
            session.send(column.value);
        }
    });
}


if (userMessage.indexOf('Email') >= 0) {
   session.send('Your are looking for your email');
   execute("select Email from StudentProfile where ID=1", rowProcessor);
   // ...
```